# can't convert T to baseEnt although have a where

Tags: c#

I have created a cycle manager using this code

```
 public class CycleManager
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<BaseCommand> m_Commands = new ConcurrentQueue<BaseCommand>();
    private EventContainer<BaseEvent> m_Container = new EventContainer<BaseEvent>();
    public void RunCommand(BaseCommand command)
    {
        m_Commands.Enqueue(command);
    }

    public void WaitForEvent<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : BaseEvent
    {
        m_Container.Add(handler);
    }
}
```

The event contain look like this:

```
public class EventContainer<TEvent> where TEvent : BaseEvent
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<TEvent>> m_eventHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<TEvent>>();

    public void Add(Action<TEvent> handler)
    {
        m_eventHandlers.Add(typeof(TEvent), handler);
    }
}
```

I'm getting error
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Action' to 'System.Action<CycleManagerTesting.Models.BaseEvent>'

in line `m_Container.Add(handler);`

I don't know how to do what I want . I just want to be able to do

```
var c = new CycleManager();
c.WaitForEvent<DoorOpenedEvent>(e =>
{
 // something with e.DoorID;
});
```

I know one of the solutions is:

```
    public void Add(Action<BaseEvent> handler)
    {
        m_eventHandlers.Add(typeof(TEvent), handler);
    }
```

but i don't want to cast everytime I'm using the method

```
var c = new CycleManager();
c.WaitForEvent<DoorOpenedEvent>(e =>
{
    var realevent = (DoorOpenedEvent)e;
});

 public class DoorOpenedEvent:BaseEvent
{
    public string DoorID { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEvent{}
```

Comment: I think you can solve it with `m_eventHandlers.Add(typeof(TEvent), (ev) => handler(ev));` As the other answer states, `Action<DerivedEvent>` cannot be casted to `Action<BaseEvent>`, but using a lambda should solve this... Edit: ah yes the comments below say the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `EventContainer<BaseEvent>.Add` expects a `Action<BaseEvent>` delegate.

However, the `WaitForEvent` method would accept and therefore try to add not only *Action<BaseEvent>*, but also `Action<DerivedEvent>` due the generic `where T : BaseEvent` constraint restricting `T` to be `BaseEvent` or **any other** possible type derived from *BaseEvent* (like `class DerivedEvent : BaseEvent { }`, for example).

But despite the *WaitForEvent* method accepting a delegate like *Action<DerivedEvent>*, it is simply impossible to pass on such a delegate to the *EventContainer<BaseEvent>.Add* method, because *Action<DerivedEvent>* is not convertible to *Action<BaseEvent>*.

One possible solution is to let the *EventContainer<TEvent>.Add* method accept not only *Action<T>*, but also "Action<derived from TEvent>". The latter will be wrapped in an anonymous or local function that itself accepts a *TEvent* parameter and thus is convertible to an *Action<TEvent>* (which then can be added to the dictionary). To enable this, a slight change in the signature of the *Add* method is required, making the method itself generic:

```
public class EventContainer<TEvent> where TEvent : BaseEvent
{
    ...

    public void Add<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : TEvent
    {
        m_eventHandlers.Add(
            typeof(T),
            (handler is Action<TEvent> handlerForTEvent)
                ? handlerForTEvent
                : InvokeHandlerWithDerivedEvent
        );

        void InvokeHandlerWithDerivedEvent(TEvent baseEvt)
        {
            if (baseEvt is T evt)
            {
                handler(evt);
            }
            else
            {
                // Ouch!
                // That is not supposed to happen.
                // Throw some exception or something...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why not I'm using WaitForEvent<DoorOpenedEvent> , it can be converted back

Comment: @Izikon, What do you mean by saying "it can be converted back"? What can be converted back to what? I am talking about the Action<T> type here that's fundamentally at the core of your problem, pay attention ;-)

Comment: look at the question I can do Action<BaseEvent>, but than I need to convert them BACK when calling the handler c.WaitForEvent<DoorOpenedEvent>(e=>{var relEvent - (DoorOpenedEvent)e;});

Comment: @Izikon That's what i **already** said in my answer: "_But Action<DerivedEvent> is of course not convertible to Action<BaseEvent>._". In other words, you cannot convert and you cannot treat a `Action<DoorOpenedEvent>` to/as `Action<BaseEvent>`. The problem is entirely and only the declaration of the WaitForEvent method, nothing else. Stop looking somewhere else for a problem that solely lies within the WaitForEvent method.

Comment: @Izikon You have a conceptual problem with your code and your assumptions. You think you can treat an `Action<DoorOpenedEvent>` like an `Action<BaseEvent>`. But you cannot, because `Action<DoorOpenedEvent>` is not convertible to `Action<BaseEvent>` (that's also basically what the error message is telling you in plain english)

Comment: I change the architecture according to the comments .Thnx!